# How to Trigger Alert only once per Buy Signal until a Sell Signal?

Tags: pine-script

I want to trigger the alert condition only once per BuySignal until a SellSignal occurs. I used this flag solution by @vitruvius from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607220/how-can-i-stop-an-alertcondition-once-its-been-activated), and it worked if I had 1 BuySignal and 1 SellSignal.

But now I have 5 Buy Signals and 1 Sell Signal. I want the alert condition to trigger only once per Buy Signal until the Sell Signal occurs.

Lets assume I have Buy Signals like these:

```
buySignal_1 = ta.crossover(a, b)

buySignal_2 = ta.crossover(c, d)

buySignal_3 = ta.crossover(e, f)

buySignal_4 = ta.crossover(g, h)

buySignal_5 = ta.crossover(i, j)
```

and 1 Sell Signal:

```
sellSignal_1 = ta.crossunder(k, l)
```

each Buy Signal can trigger only once till a Sell Signal is occurred. So I can have a maximum of only 5 Signals occur till a Sell Signal occurs. And once a Sell Signal occurs, the flag is reset and the cycle is repeated.

I tried to convert the code but it became too confusing for me. I would appreciate it if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things get complicated, think about a brute force solution.

In this case, you can have five `var` flags to see if the respective alert has been triggered. Then trigger your alarm if it has not been triggered yet. Reset the flags when there is a sell signal.

```
var buy_signal_1_alert_triggered = false
var buy_signal_2_alert_triggered = false
var buy_signal_3_alert_triggered = false

buySignal_1 = ta.crossover(a, b)
buySignal_2 = ta.crossover(c, d)
buySignal_3 = ta.crossover(e, f)

// Trigger alerts if they have not been triggered yet
alert_1 = not buy_signal_1_alert_triggered and buySignal_1
alert_2 = not buy_signal_2_alert_triggered and buySignal_2
alert_3 = not buy_signal_3_alert_triggered and buySignal_3

// Update the flags
buy_signal_1_alert_triggered := alert_1 ? true : buy_signal_1_alert_triggered
buy_signal_2_alert_triggered := alert_2 ? true : buy_signal_2_alert_triggered
buy_signal_3_alert_triggered := alert_3 ? true : buy_signal_3_alert_triggered

// Reset the flags
if (sellSignal_1)
    buy_signal_1_alert_triggered := false
    buy_signal_2_alert_triggered := false
    buy_signal_3_alert_triggered := false
```

I haven't tested this but it should work.