# How to reduce unwanted alert messages

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I receive unwanted alert messages. I would like to have only 1 "Go Long" alert when going long and then no other "Go Long" alerts until after the first "Go Short" alert. I'm having trouble getting this right.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Single Alert Strategy", overlay=true)

// Create flags to avoid multiple Long signals when already in Long and multiple Short signals when already in Short
isLong = false              // We initialize a value and give it false (we are not in a Long position)
isLong := nz(isLong[1])     // We check the previous value and assign the previous value to this variable (when no previous value exist it will become false)

isShort = false             // We initialize a value and give it false (we are not in a Short position)
isShort := nz(isShort[1])   // We check the previous value and assign the previous value to this variable (when no previous value exist it will become false)

// Long Short conditions
tot_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
bullLevel = 30
bearLevel = 70

longCondition = ta.crossover(tot_rsi, bullLevel) and not isLong     // Go Long only if we are not already Long
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(tot_rsi, bearLevel) and not isShort  // Go Short only if we are not already Short

// Change the flags to avoid duplicate signals
if (longCondition)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (shortCondition)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

if longCondition
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message = "GoLong")

if shortCondition
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, alert_message = "GoShort")

// Plot the signals and compare them with the Alerts log
plotshape(series=longCondition, title="Long", text="Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCondition, title="Short", text="Short", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
```

I followed the instructions in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607220/how-can-i-stop-an-alertcondition-once-its-been-activated). While the signal indicators plot correctly (no additional signals), I do get an alert message when there was no signal plotted. This strategy is newly created with a new alert and is only added to 1 chart. The alert was created at 06:58, there were signals plotted before the alert was created but it triggered at 07:05 even though there was no signal plotted.
RSI level at 07:05 was 48.20

Any ideas what may have caused this alert to trigger and how to prevent additional alerts like these?
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENKUD.png)

Edit: I'm testing an alternative approach. The unwanted alerts do not come frequently so I may have to run it for some time. If anyone knows of a different work around then I'm happy to give that a try.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Single Alert Strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = true)

noOrder = strategy.closedtrades == 0   // There is no previous order
openLong = strategy.position_size > 0  // We are going Long
openShort = strategy.position_size < 0 // We are going Short

// Long Short conditions
tot_rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
bullLevel = 30
bearLevel = 70

longCondition = ta.crossover(tot_rsi, bullLevel) and (openShort[1] or noOrder)  // Go Long only if the previous order was Short
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(tot_rsi, bearLevel) and (openLong[1] or noOrder) // Go Short only if the previous order was Long

if longCondition
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message = "GoLong")

if shortCondition
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, alert_message = "GoShort")

// Plot the signals and compare them with the Alerts log
plotshape(series=longCondition, title="Long", text="Long", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCondition, title="Short", text="Short", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.small)
```

Edit 2: The 2nd approach also created an alert despite there not being any signal plotted. [Screenhot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YJuJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should test also with strategy.opentrades which will return something !=0 if a trade (Long or Short) is currently open :

```
if longCondition and strategy.opentrades==0
    strategy.close_all(comment="close", immediately=true)
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message = "GoLong")

if shortCondition and strategy.opentrades==0
    strategy.close_all(comment="close", immediately=true)
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, alert_message = "GoShort")
```

Comment: I appreciate your input and previous help (my profile is new so I couldn't vote you up). I tried your approach but it didn't work. I did expect the strategy with this approach to at least being able to open one. I think strategy.opentrades==0 would become false upon the first entry, preventing any further triggers as it requires to be true. To be honest I'm out of ideas as the signals do plot correctly with the first 2 approaches. I don't understand how the plot can be correct but the alerts are still being triggered as both strategy.entry and plot use the same condition... :-)

Comment: @qwerty you should try to close your entry before opening a new strategy.entry, I update my answer accordingly. Can you edit your question and show us how you define your alert in the GUI ?