# Trading view alerts every bar close, how can i have just one?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, alerts

I have a problem:
Trading view trigger alerts every bar close which is a major problem to me, because pineconnector keeps making orders based on the alerts received.

While I have no major experience with pine script , this is a major problem to me , if anyone would help me get the alert just one until the next reverse signal, I would be more grateful.

This is the code I have on my pine script strategy :

```
if buy 
    alert(buy_alert_string,alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long)
if sell
    strategy.entry('sell', strategy.short)
    alert(sell_alert_string,alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: Maybe this question is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607220/how-can-i-stop-an-alertcondition-once-its-been-activated

Answer (score 0):

Try whith [barstate.isconfirmed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Disconfirmed)

Something like that

```
if buy and barstate.isconfirmed
    alert(buy_alert_string,alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long)

if sell and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry('sell', strategy.short)
    alert(sell_alert_string,alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: i trade this solution but unfortunately didn't work either, it keeps sending me alerts every bar close.